# Resulting matrix dimension - After whom is the rule called?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The product of two matrices A and B with dimensions (n,k) and (k,m) results in a matrix C (n,m).

I remember that my professor used to call this rule after a specific person (I guess the inventor of that rule). Do you know how the name of the person is? Or how do you call that rule in general?

Comment: That's just the rule of composition of mappings, I don't think it has a name after a person. At least I have never heard of it...

Comment: Could it be Jacques Philippe Marie Binet?